# mvc model with foreign key relationship

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

I am having data annotation validation issue with model containing model of foreign object.

Lets say

```
Class Foo
{
    public virtual Int Id {get; set;}

    [Required]       
    public virtual String Name {get; set;}
 }

 Class Bar
 {
    public virtual Int Id {get; set;}

    [Required]
    public virtual String AnotherName {get; set;}

    public virtual Foo foo  {get; set;}
 }
```

FOO is NOT mandatory/required while creating BAR.

But when i try to check the ModelState in HTTPPOST of BAR it say model state is invalid, and report the column of FOO as missing.

```
[HTTPPOST]
public ActionResult SaveBar(BAR bar)
{
if (ModelState.IsValid)
    SaveBar(bar);

}
```

I have set FOO as null, as tried TryUpdateModel, but still didnt help.

**EDIT**
I am dealing with entities and not view models

And also.. How to tell model binder not to check the FOO when binding BAR...

**EDIT**
modified example..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the model binder is instantiating Foo as a member of the Bar object when you hit 'SaveBar()'. Thus, the attribute validation on Foo fires, just as you would expect.

Here's what I would do: remove the attribute validation and just go a different route, maybe like a custom validation method that you call from the controller actions for normal "Foo" operations. "SaveBar()" can check Foo for a default state and decide to call that validation or not, depending.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work the way you think it is. The `ModelState` is invalid because you declared the fields of `Foo` as required. If your view does not accept and pass values for `Foo.Id` and `Foo.Name` then you will get an invalid `ModelState`.

Comment: but in the BAR i have not annotated FOO as required, then FOO should not be checked.... And also how to solve this problem??

Comment: Yes that's is right but it's not the Foo object itself that accepts the input but instead its fields, right. So the validation is done against the fields of Foo.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `[Required]` on your model's id. I'm not sure whether you're dealing with entities or view models here, but in general, the id should be allowed to be unset. In the case of entities, the id will not be set until it is saved to the database (typically) and in the case of a view model, you might be representing an entity that has not previously been saved (and thus has no id).

`[Required]` has only two real uses, so you should understand exactly what those are and then only apply the attribute accordingly:

1) On an entity, `[Required]` will imply NOT NULL. It really only makes sense on strings since every other scalar type is NOT NULL by default.

2) On a view model being used to accept form data from a POST. This will require that the field not be blank. If your id is not a form field being presented to the user for input (which I highly doubt it is), then it should *not* be required.

Comment: i just created the example (fixed it, Id is not marked as required) ... but the real problem i am facing is, how to avoid checking of properties of FOO during validation of BAR

Comment: That's handled by default. If you do not initialize `Foo` in `Bar`, then your property `foo` will be null, and since it's not required, validation will happily go ahead. However if `foo` is an instance of `Foo` then it *must* be valid as well for `Bar` to be valid. This is just common sense; otherwise, `ModelState.IsValid` would be meaningless because something like saving the entity to the DB would still fail as soon as it got to saving the `Foo`.

Comment: sorry, i reupdated my example to be more clear... the fields are defined as properties... and it is checking for FOO in BAR... the properties n virtual requirement comes from NHibernate

Comment: Why in the world are you making scalar properties virtual? That's sort of beside the point, though. Nothing you've added detracts from what I said in my last comment. If `foo` is initialized and has *any* required properties, they *must* be filled in for the model to validate. Again, this is common sense. If `Bar` has a `Foo` and that `Foo` is invalid, `Bar` is inherently invalid as well. It's like trying to take the engine out of your car and saying the car still has a gas pedal so it should still go down the road.

Comment: but FOO is optional.. still i will have to provide values for it.. getting confused.... also virtual scalar properties is requirement of Nhibernate...

Comment: Your property `foo` *is* optional. Somewhere in your code, though, it's being set with an instantiated `Foo`, and *that* is why it's being validated. If `foo` is set to anything other than null, then that thing it's set with must be valid in order for `Bar` to be valid. Period. Not really sure how to be any more clear.

Answer (score 0):

@hgrathi, what you are not understanding is that as soon as you made Name in Foo Required, Foo is now Required under Bar.

One way to solve this is to create a custom model binder by implementing IModelBinder.